# In-App Purchase is successful (.purchased), function is called but the variable does not maintain its new value

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase

I am having trouble setting up my In App Purchases on Swift 4 in Xcode.

The purchase goes through successfully, I know this because the following is printed out into the console.

"Adding product to payment queue

purchased com.taptrudel.ZenHangman.Zap

ProductID : com.taptrudel.ZenHangman.Zap

Gave user 10 zaps, new zap count: 13

numberOfZaps = 3"

```
extension IAPService: SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for transaction in transactions {
        print(transaction.transactionState.status(), transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
        switch transaction.transactionState {
        case .purchasing, .deferred: break // do nothing
        case .purchased:
            queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
            givePurchasedProduct(productID: transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
        case .restored:
            self.restorePurchase()
            queue.finishTransaction(transaction)

       case .failed:
            queue.finishTransaction(transaction)

        }
    }
}
}
```

The extension above calls givePurchasedProduct(productId: String) once the purchase state becomes .purchased

That function is just below here, it simply passes in the productId to a function in my game scene which will give the user the consumable he just purchased.

```
func givePurchasedProduct(productID: String) {

        guard let gameScene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") else { return }
        gameScene.givePurchasedProduct(productId: productID)
    }
```

Now if you look below we are in my GameScene.

```
func givePurchasedProduct(productId: String) {
        print("ProductID : \(productId)")
        if productId.range(of: "Zap") != nil {
            numberOfZaps += 10
            print("Gave user 10 zaps, new zap count: \(numberOfZaps)")
            // TODO: CALL SAVE DATA HERE
        }
    }
```

If you return to the message from the console which I pasted at the top of this post, you will see that

1. Purchase state becomes .purchased
2. givePurchasedProduct() is called
3. We successfully add (10) zaps (user starts with 3) for a total of (13) to the numberOfZaps variable.
4. Immediately after this, I touch the background anywhere as I made it so this would print the number of zaps to make sure everything was working. As you can see... without any actions in between adding 10 zaps and printing the number of zaps, I somehow seem to have lost them... numberOfZaps is set back to 3 immediately.
5. I searched my entire project for every time that I set "numberOfZaps" to try and identify the problem although it is only set once at the top of my game scene with the other variables.
6. I am hopeless as I have been **struggling with this issue for days**.
   Only thing I can think of is that given that these are sandbox test purchases that the variable somehow reverts to its original value given that no real payment has actually been made

**THANKS A MILLION FOR TAKING THE TIME YOU ARE AWESOME**

ps. I just noticed that if I used (2) "zaps" for example. Leaving me with (1) zap from the original (3) that every user is given.

Initialization shown below.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    var level = 1

    var gameStarted = false

    var numberOfZaps = 3
```

Although when I buy (10) more zaps.

The expected behaviour would be to see the user now have (11) zaps

Although my console is showing me that we once again have (13) zaps after purchase.  So it seems like it it adding 10 to the original value of 3 regardless of where the counter currently is.

But as usual, immediately after I click okay on the confirmation of my new zaps, When I check the numberOfZaps we are back at (3). (not 13, not 11..)

I really dont know what else I can do here.

The only time **numberOfZaps** is modified is in 3 different places

1) Once when it is initialized at the top of my gameScene

2) When a user buys (10) zaps, I add (10) to numberOfZaps

3) When a user uses a zap during a level, I subtract (1) from numberOfZaps

When I subtract (1) zap, the counter works perfectly and maintains the data, although when I add (10) zaps regardless of where the counter currently is, I end up with (13) zaps for just enough time to print my statement, it seems as soon as I leave the function, my zaps return to (3).

For this reason, I also tried adding "self." before "numberOfZaps" to make sure I was referencing the correct instance of the variable.

Thank you!

Comment: You'd better make it concise.  Nobody is going to read it all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `givePurchasedProduct` function, you are creating a new `GameScene` instance, changing its number of zaps, and then the `GameScene` object is discarded. Whichever other `GameScene` object you have, which ostensibly controls the real game scene that your app is showing, is not modified.